# Use VBA to INSERT a new record into an Access 2007 database

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2007

I am still trying to learn, so please be gentle.
My goal is to track users who've completed viewing a standalone MS PowerPoint by having them click a button on the last slide.

When the completeButton is clicked, it captures the Windows username and date. How can I have the event also insert both the variables as a new record into an existing MS Access 2007 database (behind the scenes)?

```
'Click button
Private Sub completeButton_Click()
'Get Windows user
Dim empUserName As String
empUserName = Environ("UserName")
'Get Date
Dim Completed As Date
Completed = Date
'Set Path to database
Dim Path As String
Path = "C:\TestDatabase.accdb"

'Open connection to database
'Insert empUserName and Completed variables as new record
'Close connection to database
'Display message
Msgbox("Thank you for viewing the material")
'Close presentation
With Application.Presentations
For i = .Count To 1 Step -1
    .Item(i).Close
Next
End With
```

Comment: At some point, I'll need to build reporting functionality into the databse to identify which users have viewed which materials by a given date(as there will be numerous powerpoints that this functionality will need to be incorporated into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on Office 2013, hope it would work for you too. These lines open connection, insert new entries and close the connection.

```
Dim Path As String
Dim strCon As String
Dim con As Object

Path = "C:\TestDatabase.accdb"
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Path
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")

con.Open strCon
con.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1, Field2) VALUES (""" & empUserName & """, """ & Completed & """)"

con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Table1 - your table name
Field1 - name of the column where you want to put `empUserName`
Field2 - name of the column where you want to put `Completed`

Comment: I'm getting a runtime error 429 activex component can't create object...might have something to do with windows 10 and regsvr32 dao360.dll ? At any rate, I appreciate your input and I'll give it a shot on another system in the meantime.

Comment: Ok, let me know how it goes. I'm not yet familiar with win10. Is it this line where the error stops you: `Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")` ?

Comment: Based on what you provided, I was able to get it working! Thanks again for the direction! I learned something!

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by one command:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO C:\TestDatabase.accdb.Table1 ( Field1, Field2 ) VALUES (""" & empUserName & """, """ & Completed & """);"
```

You can add

```
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
```

before inserting in order to suppress warning.